# 403 Access denied while accessing AWS S3 from local Intellij setup

Tags: amazon-s3, intellij-idea, http-status-code-403, access-denied, aws-sts

In my new laptop I am not able to access s3 from my local Intellij. I have already generated aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key and aws_session_token.
This is how my ~/.aws/config file looks:

```
[profile diksha@**.com]
region = ap-south-1
output = json

[profile diksha@**.com-mfa]
region = ap-south-1
output = text

[profile dev-role]
region = ap-south-1
output = json
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::03************5:role/dev-role
source_profile = diksha@**.com-mfa
```

And this is how my ~/.aws/credentials looks like:

```
[diksha.nagpal@**.com]
aws_access_key_id = A****************3
aws_secret_access_key = j*******************************F

[diksha.nagpal@**.com-mfa]
aws_access_key_id = A****************R
aws_secret_access_key = 2*******************************V
aws_session_token = IQ**********************Q==

[dev-role]
region = ap-south-1
output = json
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::03************5:role/cult-pass-devs
source_profile = diksha@**.com-mfa
```

Then I set up AWS toolkit in my Intellij. I'm able to see files in the AWS Explorer but still not able to build the project. Can someone please help? I'm getting this error while building the project:

```
(s3://<bucket_name>/<file_path>): Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: WWQG7VF81Z2323GW, AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, AWS Error Message: Access Denied
```

Comment: Can you give a bit of more context here. The project you are trying to build does `dev-role` have access and permissions for that?

Comment: I don't think the `credentials` file should reference a `role_arn` or a `source_profile`. I normally only see them in the `config` file. Plus, the roles you have configured in the two files differ (`dev-role` vs `cult-pass-devs`). I'd suggest removing those lines from the credentials file and confirming the access permissions granted to `dev-role`.